# Dificuldade com laço for em Ruby

Tags: ruby, loop

Estou com dificuldades de exibir dinamicamente o conteúdo de variáveis.
Por ex:

```
        minha_var_1 = %{Um texto}  
        minha_var_2 = %{Outro texto}  
        minha_var_3 = %{Mais outro texto}
```

Mas, já tentei exibir tanto com:

```
        for i in(0..2)  
          puts minha_var_"#{i}"  
        end
```

Como:

```
        for i in(0..2)  
          puts "minha_var_#{i}"  
        end
```

Sem lograr sucesso.

Qual seria a maneira correta de exibir este conteúdo dinamicamente?

Comment: puts( '­­­ loop #1 ­­­' )
for i in ["texto1","texto2","texto3"]  do 
        puts( i )
end   seria isso que tu quer?

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @haykou, mas testei e não funcionou...

Comment: Usando array eu consigo fazer a exibição, mas sem a utilização de arrays nada...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você realmente quer acessar múltiplas variáveis em um loop, a linguagem permite isso. Pode usar a perigosa função `eval`, que recebe como argumento um código no formato de uma string e o executa. Assim `eval("1+1")` resulta em `2` e `eval("system 'shutdown now'")` desliga o seu computador. Portanto você pode acessar suas variáveis usando `eval("minha_var_1")` ou `eval("minha_var_2")`. É uma questão de construir a string certa e passar para o `eval`.

```
minha_var_1 = "Um texto"
minha_var_2 = "Outro texto"
minha_var_3 = "Mais outro texto"

for i in 1..3
  puts eval("minha_var_#{i}")
end
```

Mas, é claro, não existe nenhum motivo concebível para você querer usar um código assim. Use arrays ou um hash para essa tarefa:

Usando Array:

```
minha_array = ["Um texto", "Outro texto", "Mais outro texto"]

for i in 0..2     # note que arrays contam a partir do zero
  puts minha_array[i]
end
```

Usando Hash:

```
meu_hash = {
  1 => "Um texto",
  2 => "Outro texto"
  3 => "Mais outro texto"
}

for i in 1..3
  puts minha_array[i]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Creio que a solução utilizando uma array é a mais apropriada.

```
# Declarando as variáveis
var1 = "um texto"
var2 = "outro texto"

# Atribuindo o valor das variáveis ao array
array = [var1, var2]

# Realizando a iteração através de cada item do array para que seja exibido na tela
array.each do |item|
  puts item
end
```

O resultado exibido no console será:

```
um texto
outro texto
```

Answer (score 0):

Propensa solução fazendo uso de arrays:

```
    #criando o array de strings
    minha_var = [%{Um texto}, %{Outro texto}, %{Mais outro texto}]
    #exibindo o array com laço for
    for i in(0..2)
      puts minha_var[i]
    end
```

Mas não achei uma solução sem a utilização de arrays...